# Converting vertex colours to UV coordinates

Tags: python, scripting, uv, geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

So I've got a colour attribute that needs to be converted into a UV map. My color attribute just so happens to only be using R and G values, and what I want is for the R value to be converted into the X value on the UV map, while the G value is converted into an inverted Y value.

I was hoping that this might be accomplished using Geometry Nodes, but I would need help designing the node tree. Otherwise, if anyone would be willing to write a script to do this, then I could accept that too.

Comment: in 3.6 you have to store the uv map as a *2D vector* attribute type, and then when you apply the GN modifier the attribute will automatically become a uv map.

Comment: Thanks, I also figured out that I can import the vertex colours with the Named Attribute node 